# Divide Spark DataFrame data into separate files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, amazon-s3, qubole

I have the following DataFrame input from a s3 file and need to transform the data into the following desired output. I am using Spark version 1.5.1 with Scala, but could change to Spark with Python. Any suggestions are welcome.

DataFrame Input:

```
name    animal   data
john    mouse    aaaaa
bob     mouse    bbbbb
bob     mouse    ccccc
bob     dog      ddddd
```

Desired Output:

```
john/mouse/file.csv
bob/mouse/file.csv
bob/dog/file.csv

terminal$ cat bob/mouse/file.csv
bbbbb
ccccc

terminal$ cat bob/dog/file.csv
ddddd
```

Here is my existing Spark Scala code that I have tried:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf())
val sqlc = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlc.read.json("raw.gz")
val cols = Seq("name", "animal")
df.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).count().take(100).foreach(println)
```

Current Output:

```
[john,mouse,1]
[bob,mouse,2]
[bob,dog,1]
```

Some of the problems with my existing code is that the groupBy returns a GroupedData object and I probably don't want to do a count/sum/agg function on that data. I am looking for a better technique to group and output the data. The dataset is very large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved using `partitionBy` option of the `DataFrameWriter`. General syntax is as follows:

```
df.write.partitionBy("name", "animal").format(...).save(...)
```

Unfortunately the only plain text format which support partitioning in Spark 1.5 is JSON.

If you can update Spark installation to:

- 1.6 - you can use `partitionBy` with `text` format. 1.6 is also required if you need a single output file for group (`repartition`).
- 2.0 - you can use `partitionBy` with `csv` format.

I believe that in 1.5 your best option is to write files as JSON and convert individual output files.

If number of distinct `name', 'animals` is small you can try to perform separate write for each group:

```
val dist = df.select("name", "animal").rdd.collect.map {
  case Row(name: String, animal: String) => (name, animal)
}

for {
  (name, animal) <- dist
} df.where($"name" === name && $"animal" === animal)
    .select($"data").write.format("csv").save(s"/prefix/$name/$animal")
```

but this won't scale when number of combinations grows.